# classed image not aligning vertically

Tags: flexbox, vertical-alignment

My flex container holds three divs,
every div has property of `flex-grow`

I have a classed image that does not work on `align-items: center;`

this is the flex container

```
.top-container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 70px;
}
```

and this is the container inside

```
.top-notifications {
    flex-grow: 6;
    background-color: #F8F9F9;
    text-align: right;
     align-items: center;
}
```

and the image class is

```
.user-picture {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 100%; 
    -moz-border-radius: 100%; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
}
```

every elements in boxes are aligned centered but the classed image

Comment: can you add the html code please :)

Comment: heres fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xzoam3wj/1/

Comment: images stay on top

Comment: can't post anymore

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bmjjBL try this. here is a guide to flex https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.top-container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 70px;
}

.logo {
   background-color: #EAFAF1;
  
   display:flex;
   align-items:center;
}

.top-menu {
    background-color: #FEF9E7;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}

.top-notifications {
  flex-grow: 1;
 
  display:flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  
  background-color: #F8F9F9;  
}


/* top menu */
.top-menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #FEF9E7;
    
}

.top-menu li {
    float: left;
}

.top-menu li a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 5px;
}

.top-menu li a:hover {
    background-color: #85C1E9;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}
/* end top menu */

.user-picture {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 100%; 
    -moz-border-radius: 100%; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="top-container">
        <div class="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" class="logo" />              </div>
        <div class="top-menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a class="active" href="#home">Dashboard</a></li>
          <li><a href="#news">Users</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Settings</a></li>
        </ul>  
          
        </div>
          <div class="top-notifications">
             
                Notifications<i class="fa fa-bell-o fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;
                Reports<i class="fa fa-flag fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;
                <img src="images/boy.png" class="user-picture" />
          </div>
      </div>
```

`align-items:center;` is used on the flex parent, not on the flex item itself. See [css flex guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)